# Question on the kernel dimensions for convolutions on mel filter bank features

Tags: deep-learning, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, convolution

I am currently trying to understand the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08581.pdf. I am struggling to understand a part about how a convolution is performed on an input of log mel filterbank features:

> We train seq2seq models for both end-to-end speech translation, and a baseline model for speech recognition. We found
> that the same architecture, a variation of that from [10], works
> well for both tasks. We use 80 channel log mel filterbank features extracted from 25ms windows with a hop size of 10ms,
> stacked with delta and delta-delta features. The output softmax
> of all models predicts one of 90 symbols, described in detail in
> Section 4, that includes English and Spanish lowercase letters.
> The encoder is composed of a total of 8 layers. The input
> features are organized as a T × 80 × 3 tensor, i.e. raw features,
> deltas, and delta-deltas are concatenated along the ’depth’ dimension. This is passed into a stack of two convolutional layers
> with ReLU activations, each consisting of 32 kernels with shape
> 3 × 3 × depth in time × frequency. These are both strided by
> 2 × 2, downsampling the sequence in time by a total factor of 4,
> decreasing the computation performed in the following layers.
> Batch normalization [26] is applied after each layer.

As I understand it, the input to the convolutional layer is 3 dimensional (number of 25 ms windows (T) x 80 (features for each window) x 3 (features, delta features and delta-delta features). However, the kernels used on those inputs seem to have 4 dimensions and I do not understand why that is. Wouldn't a 4 dimensional kernel need a 4 dimensional input? In my head, the input has the same dimensions as a rgb picture: width (time) x height (frequency) x color channels (features, delta features and delta-delta features). Therefore I would think of a kernel for a 2D convolution as a filter of size a (filter width) x b (filter height) x 3 (depth of the input). Am I missing something here? What is wrong about my idea or what is done different in this paper?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: Did you figure it out? Imo it's weird to concatenate these inputs and then apply a convolution the way they do it in the first place. There will be two adjacent but different features which will be convolved. This does not feel right. But I agree, it's also weird that they state a 4D kernel here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, turns out it was just a misunderstanding from my side: the authors are using 32 kernels of shape 3x3, which results (after two layers with 2x2 striding) in an output of shape t/4x20x32 where t stands for the time dimension.